# Getting "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java

On executing this code, I am getting a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException  on line 81. I know posting entire code is against bet practices, but I thought it would be quite difficult to convey what I am doing unless I post the entire code.

Basically I wanted to remove all occurrences of an element from a List, so I am doing    List.removeAll(Collection). I cannot understand what am I doing wrong on Line 81. Thanks for help!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;;


public class MinCutClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    private HashMap verticeMap ;
    private List edgeList ;


    public MinCutClass()
    {
          verticeMap = new HashMap();
          edgeList = new ArrayList();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MinCutClass minCutObj = new MinCutClass();

        minCutObj.populateVertices();
        minCutObj.printVerticeMap();
        minCutObj.printVerticeMap1();

        minCutObj.populateEdges();

        //minCutObj.printEdgeList();

        minCutObj.findMinCut();

//      minCutObj.printEdgeList();
    //  minCutObj.printVerticeMap();


    }

    private void printEdgeList()
    {
        Iterator i = edgeList.iterator();

        while(i.hasNext())
        {

            System.out.println(i.next());
        }

    }

    private void printVerticeMap()
    {

        Set s = verticeMap.entrySet();
        Iterator i = s.iterator();


        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            Entry e = (Entry)i.next();

            System.out.println("Key :" + e.getKey() + " Value :" + e.getValue());

        }

    }

    private void printVerticeMap1()
    {
        Collection c = new TreeSet();
        c.add("2");
        List temp = (List)verticeMap.get("1");
        System.out.println(temp.getClass().getName());
        temp.removeAll(c);

    }

    private void findMinCut()
    {


        while (verticeMap.keySet().size() > 2 ) // as long as there are more than two vertices
        {

            int randomEdgeIndex = chooseRandomEdgeIndex(); //choose a random edge basically any random index in edgeList
            String randomEdgeChosen = (String)edgeList.get(randomEdgeIndex);

            //Edge contraction

            //1. remove the edges from edgeList. We want to avoid self loops. There may exist many edges of this type.
            Collection c = new TreeSet();
            c.add(edgeList.get(randomEdgeIndex));
            edgeList.removeAll(c); //removeAll , all edges are removed
            c.clear();

            //get edge vertices
            String [] tempArr = randomEdgeChosen.split("_");
            String v1 =  tempArr[0];
            String v2 = tempArr[1];


            //2.a Delete v2 from v1 vertices list, the contracting edge vanishes. Please note, all parallel edges are also being removed as they create self loops.
            List tempListV1 = (List)verticeMap.get(v1);
            c.add(v2);
            tempListV1.removeAll(c);
            c.clear();


            //2.b Now delete v1 from v2 vertices list, the contracting edge and all parallel edges are removed as they create self loops. 
            List tempListV2 = (List)verticeMap.get(v2);
            c.add(v1);
            tempListV2.removeAll(c);
            c.clear();

            //3. Now add all vertices v2 is connected with in v1 list because the resultant merged node is v1
            Iterator i = tempListV2.iterator();

            List tempListEle;

            while (i.hasNext())
            {
                String ele = (String)i.next();
                tempListEle = (List)verticeMap.get(ele); //get the vertice list for the current element (from v2 list) being considered  as v1 has to be added to that list and v2 removed.


                tempListV1.add(ele);
                //tempListV2.remove(ele); //this is not needed , as entry for v2 in verticeMap will be deleted

                tempListEle.add(v1);
                tempListEle.remove(v2);

            }


            verticeMap.remove(v2); //once all v2 elements are added to entries for all v2 elements are also updated remove entry for v2 in verticeMap

        }


    }

    private int chooseRandomEdgeIndex()
    {
        return new Random().nextInt(edgeList.size()); 
    }

    private void populateVertices()
    {
        List list = readFile(); // get a list of String arrays
        Iterator i = list.iterator(); 
        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            String[] tempArr  = (String[])i.next(); // get current String array
            String node = tempArr[0]; //get the node number

            tempArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(tempArr, 1, tempArr.length ); //create a String array with 0th element removed 


            //System.out.println(node + "" + Arrays.asList(tempArr) + this.verticeMap.getClass().getName());
            //System.out.println(node + "" + Arrays.asList(tempArr));

            this.verticeMap.put(node, Arrays.asList(tempArr)); // put the node and the nodes it has edges with in a HashMap

            //System.out.println(node + "" + verticeMap.get(node).toString());

        }


        //System.out.println("1" + "" + verticeMap.get("1").toString());

    }

    private void populateEdges()
    {
        List list = readFile(); // get a list of String arrays
        Iterator i = list.iterator(); 
        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            String[] tempArr  = (String[])i.next(); // get current String array
            String node = tempArr[0]; //get the node number 

            for(int count = 1 ; count <= tempArr.length - 1; count++) 
            {
                if(getInt(node) < getInt(tempArr[count]) ) //add the edge to the edgeList only if the node is smaller than other node being considered. This way you only add each edge only once for each pair of vertices.
                {

                    //System.out.println(node + tempArr[count]);
                    edgeList.add(""+node+"_"+tempArr[count]);

                }
            }
        }

//       i = edgeList.iterator();
//       while (i.hasNext())
//       {
//           System.out.println(i.next().toString());
//           
//       }

    }

    private List readFile()
    {
        List list = new ArrayList(); // list of String arrays
            try
            {
                 FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/ankura/Desktop/KargerAdj.txt");

                  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                  String strLine;
                  String[] strArr;
                  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
                  {

                      strLine = strLine.trim();
                      strArr = strLine.split("\\W+");

                      list.add(strArr);

                  }

                  in.close();

             }

             catch (Exception e)
             {
                //Catch exception if any
              System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
             }

            return list;

    }


    public int getInt(Object o)
    {

        return Integer.parseInt((String)o);

    }
}
```

Output / StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.removeAll(Unknown Source)
    at MinCutClass.printVerticeMap1(MinCutClass.java:81)
    at MinCutClass.main(MinCutClass.java:32)
Key :3 Value :[2, 4]
Key :2 Value :[1, 3, 4]
Key :1 Value :[2, 4]
Key :4 Value :[1, 2, 3]
java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
```

Comment: A stacktrace would be most helpful...

Comment: This would benefit from a http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  Arrays.asList(tempArr)
```

[returns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) a *fixed-size* list backed by that array. You cannot remove elements from (or add elements to) it.

Note that the list returned by Arrays.asList remains backed by that array, so that when you update elements in the list, it will change them in the array as well.

If you need a modifiable copy, use

```
new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(tempArr))
```