# Make a list and initialize it to include all the values of an Enum

Tags: java, list, enums

I have an enum `Direction` and I want to make a temporary list of all the values of that enum and then be able to remove or add values to that list.

```
public enum Direction {
    TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM, LEFT
}

List<Direction> directions = Arrays.asList(Direction.values());

directions.remove(0); // error
directions.add(Direction.BOTTOM); // error
```

With my current code, when I remove element at 0, or if I add any element, I get a run time exception `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`. So I suppose this way the list I get is immutable ? How can I do this properly ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082356/getting-main-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception)

Comment: Your intuition is correct: the concept of a set values whose membership is determined at compile-time ought not be modifiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Arrays#asList` returns a `List` that doesn't support `add` or `remove` elements since just wraps an array. Instead, create a new `ArrayList` and pass the result of `Arrays#asList` as parameter:

```
List<Direction> directions = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Direction.values()));
```

Comment: Oh, this is interesting. This is working, thanks a lot.